# My female cat (1.5yo) has been attacking my male cat(9yo) since Saturday night

Tags: cats, behavior, stress

Lily(F1.5) has been attacking Charlie(M9) since Saturday night and i don't know why. The only changes that happened was my other cat, Daisy(F3) came back from the vet clinic after staying there overnight for some medical issues.

Lily has never fully liked Charlie but they were still cordial with each other. Now she full on chases him and scratches him. Mind you, Charlie is a big kitty. He's about 5kg while Lily is around 2.8kg. He usually can defend himself but he refuses to fight against Lily and just tries to run away. These fights are stressing Daisy a lot as she is still recovering. Charlie could be minding his own business like eating or walking around and Lily will just come to him to attack him.

What is going on? It's definitely not a medical issue since she is amazing with Daisy and us. Could it be that she knows that Daisy is still a bit fragile and is protecting her? Charlie doesn't attack Daisy either.

I want her to stop as Charlie is an outside cat and lately he's been going to the neighbors because of this. I don't like that as he's already been poisoned twice in the past. And he shouldn't have to be afraid to come in his own home. He deserves to feel safe. They all do. Please help!

Comment: Who of them is neutered?

Comment: It might simply be that Lily smelled something on Daisy and associated that smell with something entirely unrelated and then took it out of Charlie.

Answer (score 1):

A vet visit can cause this behaviour in your cats,the cat returning home will have a differet smell and this can trigger what you see.

If your cats have separate cat beds you can try to switch their bedding so one cat lays on the other cats bedding when they sleep,this is to transfer the scent of your cats to eachother.

If your cats smell the same they are less likely to fight,i think things will be back to normal soon for you and your cats.

If you give your angry cat some intense playtime so she gets tired she will have less energy to fight,intense play is chasing objects,running,jumping up and down the cat tree,be sure not to force your cat to play for too long keep an eye on the breath of your cat if it is too fast you stop playing.

Comment: Coming back from the vet, Hazel always hissed at Harry, presumably because of the smell... but I preferred to interpret it as "This is all _your_ fault". Hazel always calmed down after a few hours of grumpiness.